# What version of openjdk8's source do I get to build update 131, same as oracle's latest? jdk8/jdk8u?

Tags: build, java

I'm trying for a few days to build my own jdk8 on RHEL 7.3. Until now I was using the source here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/

But there is also http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/

1) What are the differences between the two?

2) Which one do I have to choose to get update 131 (same as oracle for now)?

When I download the source and do `hg tags`:

a)In jdk8, there is one **jdk8-b131** with tag **939**

b)In jdk8u, there is plenty of jdk8:

**jdk8-b131** with tag **955**

**jdk8u131-b00** with tag **1888**

up to **jdk8u131-b11** with tag **1915**

Could anyone explain to me what genius is managing this? And where do I get THE source to build my jdk at home? And Why?

Thx,
Animal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of this is very silly. It's a result of how OpenJDK 8's initial development and updates are two different OpenJDK projects.

- The [JDK 8 Project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) was responsible for developing and releasing OpenJDK 8 initially.

  - They used http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/ as their repository
  - They used http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/jdk8-dev as their mailing list.
- The [JDK 8 Updates Project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/) is responsible for developing and releasing the post-release updates to OpenJDK 8.

  - They use http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/ as their repositoriy
  - They use http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/jdk8u-dev as their mailing list.

In other words, do not use `jdk8/jdk8`! They contain unpatched vulnerabilities.

Lets break down the tag format used in OpenJDK 8 `jdk8(uXYZ)-bABC`

- `jdk8` indicates that this is a JDK 8 or Update
- `uXYZ` indicates what JDK 8 Update this tag indicates
- `bABC` is the build number of this particular update. Build numbers are meaningless to us outside Oracle. They correspond to some internal build numbers.

The `jdk8-bXYZ` tags should be identical between jdk8u and jdk8, since the update repository contains all the tags from the initial jdk8 repository. The `jdk8uXYZ-bABC` tags are the ones you want. These tags are in numerical order. `jdk8u131-b00` is an earlier version compared to `jdk8u131-b11`.

So, if you want the latest JDK 8 Update, look at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/ (or basically the same contents but gets updates (possibly)  faster: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/), find the `jdk8uXYZ-bABC` tag where `XYZ` is the highest value (pick `jdk8u121` over `jdk8u23`) and then pick the one with the highest ABC value (pick `jdk8u121-b02` over `jdk8u121-b01` and `jdk8u49-b24`). Keep in mind that it may be an in-development version!

If you know you want something analogous to Oracle's JDK 8 Update 131, look for the `jdk8u131-ABC` tag with the highest value of `ABC` (appears to be `jdk8u131-b11`). The tags don't change after Oracle's public release of similarly-numbered update.

Everyone agrees this is a bad versioning system. I know some people who publicly objected against this weird repository system too, and I agree with them.

The tags are getting fixed for OpenJDK 9 via [JEP 223](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223) (see "Mercurial changeset tags").